# Alert from os: app may slow down your iPhone

Tags: iphone, architecture, ios10

Hy,

I have uploaded the app to App Store with both architecture. Please see the attached image for `Build Settings` of `TARGETS` in `Architectures`. And luckily it get Ready for sale, but iPhone 5s giving alert.

[image]

The alert is: "APP" may slow down your iPhone. The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.

I googled but do not found solution to get rid off this alert. On other hand i also need to support iPhone5 and prior (32 bit architectures). Please help.

Comment: Please check below url for more information for your issues. 1) http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/ios-10-1-adds-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone-warning-for-32-bit-apps-1524181, 2) http://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/06/ios-10-1-32-bit-app-alert/

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma Thanks for help but already gone through this link its from NDTV, wouldn't helpful for developers like me and you. Solution of this error should be given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have 'Architecture Priority' `LSArchitecturePriority` in your Info.plist. I had `Intel (32-bit)` for some unknown reason. Deleting this key solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that Build Active Architecture Only, as shown in your screen shot, is set to Yes. This means that you are not building an app that contains *both* 32-bit *and* 64-bit architectures; you are only building for *one* architecture. And from what you say, that architecture must have been the 32-bit architecture.

Comment: This is the best answer and I would add that keeping 'Build Active Architecture Only' set as YES for Debug while NO for Release/Distribution is probably best since you want fast building while debugging (that alert doesn't matter for debug purposes)

Answer (score 8):

> Problem :- This issue is because you are supporting 32bit architecture
>
> Solution :- armv7 is 32 bit processor, u might have to remove that
>   from architectures list

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) is the list of processors and their architectures

iPhone 5S has 64bit processor, so removing armv7 will not have any impact for iPhone 5S you can find the list of devices and their configuration in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) link

Comment: So this is the only solution to remove the armv7 from architectures, so as will not support iPhone 5-5c & prior models??

Comment: have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 8):

What fixed this for me was going into TARGET > 'Build Settings' and then under 'Valid Architectures' I added arm64 to the two that were already there, armv7 and armv7s. Also, ensure 'Build Active Architecture Only' is set to no.

Answer (score 2):

Get the .IPA file which you had uploaded and Change the extension to .Zip and Unzip the file

And open the terminal and execute the below command,
     file ~/SOME_PATH/Payload/.app/

you'll get the architecture details for the IPA

Comment: What is your command supposed to do ? It just tell me that "ICantWait.app" is a directory

Answer (score 2):

In Addition,
main cause for this problem is below ways to look out

1. Your iOS app is not up to date of iOS device version/apple guidelines
2. If your app containing outdated libs
3. If your app is 32 bit Arc family and trying to run in 64 bit arch iOS OS