# The message reads: “[App Name] may slow down your iPhone”

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

When i build and achieve the app and run on actual device which is iphone 4s(9.3.5) and iphone 5(10.2.1) this both device is 32bit. but when i run the app on iphone 6 which is 64 bit i receive this message. “The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.”

[image: may slow down your iphone]

Comment: Maybe check this > http://stackoverflow.com/a/40545885/499581

Comment: Check if you have 'Architecture Priority' LSArchitecturePriority in your Info.plist

Comment: @SivajeeBattina no i dont see Architecture priority on my info.plist