# When is the alert "App may slow down your iPhone" shown?

Tags: ios, 64-bit

A customer showed me a screenshot of my app, where the alert "App may slow down your iPhone" is shown. The problem is: I never got this alert. I started the app in the simulator (I deleted it and started it again because I think it only comes when you start the app for the first time), I tried it on a real device, but it was never shown. The problem is: I want to solve the problem and convert the app to 64 Bit, but how can I be sure it really works if I never see this alert?? I'd really appreciate some clues.

Comment: did your app uses background data fetching ? or any task that would always run, even in background

Comment: Why do you ask this question @MOHAMMADISHAQ ?

Comment: @CedricSoubrie My idea was if some apps use location etc always in the background that can also cause this alert but I answered this below. This comment was before posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem :- This issue is because you are supporting 32bit architecture
>
> Solution :- armv7 is 32 bit processor, u might have to remove that
>   from architectures list

For more explanation check following answers and forums.Hoping these will solve your issue:

[Alert from os: app may slow down your iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359182/alert-from-os-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone)

https://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/06/ios-10-1-32-bit-app-alert/

http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/ios-10-1-adds-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone-warning-for-32-bit-apps-1524181